# How to draw a popup layout in flutter/dart?

Tags: design-patterns, flutter, dart, popup

I'm new to flutter/dart and usually I use storyboard/android-design-view to design the app. But in flutter/dart I couldn't find any design-editor. So now I wanna try to draw the popup by code!

[This is design I'm trying to draw](https://ibb.co/QvypRCJ)

Also, I would be really happy if there were any guide that somebody could recommend on how to draw design programatically for dart/flutter.

Best regards!

Comment: You probably are looking for an ```showDialog``` method, could [this](https://nextfunc.com/how-to-show-dialog-in-flutter/) be helpful. Nowadays the supported ides for flutter like vs code and android studio not support a preview for the widgets but the [hot reload](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/hot-reload) could replace momentarily.

Comment: Wonderful! I just found a way on doing this and it does the job well. Thank you very much for the link, that will definitively help me out. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
showDialog<void>(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) => AlertDialog()
)
```

In AlertBox you can add Container widget and etc. and you can modified Alertbox like it do not closed until you press button and many things.